# Adding custom data at the beginning of UDP datagram data field (in linux kernel)

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, udp

I'm trying to implement a custom transport protocol which runs on top of UDP. I want to add the header for this protocol at the beginning of the UDP data field just before the data from user space is copied to skbuff.I also want to process this data just before UDP hands it off to the socket so that I can extract the header and do the required processing in the kernel. So,

1. How do I ensure that my header (say `struct new_header`) is added at the beginning of the data in the `udp_sendmsg()` function. I assume this should be copied to the data field of skbuff before any actual data from user space is copied to it or at the latest, before the UDP checksum is calculated on the data. Where exactly does this happen in the code?
2. Where exactly in `udp_recvmsg()` function is the data handed off to the socket? I think it's `skb_copy_datagram_iovec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I ensure that my header (say struct new_header) is added at the beginning of the data in the udp_sendmsg() function. I assume this
>   should be copied to the data field of skbuff before any actual data
>   from user space is copied to it or at the latest, before the UDP
>   checksum is calculated on the data. Where exactly does this happen in
>   the code?

2 options you can consider:
1.If you implement your protocol in userspace, then you can just use UDP socket to talk to kernel, and do protocol decap after you receive datagram from UDP socket or encap before you send data to UDP socket.
2.If you want to implement your protocol in kernel space.Then you have to implement you own socket type.You can check out some tunnel socket code already existed in kernel source as example(eg.L2TP). Once you get your socket type registered in kernel, then your socket data sent from userspace to kernel space will handle by your encap code (something equivalent to udp_sendmsg()),and then you encap code in turn calls udp_sendmsg() to further down to the network stack.

> Where exactly in udp_recvmsg() function is the data handed off to the socket? I think it's skb_copy_datagram_iovec().

Not sure which version of kernel you are looking at. For kernel 4.6, it is skb_copy_datagram_msg() -->  skb_copy_datagram_iter(). This is where the datagram is copied to a buff and then return to userspace.
Actually, udp_recvmsg() is called when the userspace try to receive data from the socket, so udp_recvmsg() is already in socket context.
Network stack hands off the datagram to socket in sock_queue_rcv_skb(),by putting the datagram in sk_receive_queue. 
Call chain in kernel 4.6 like this:

```
__udp4_lib_rcv -->
  udp_queue_rcv_skb(sk, skb); -->  sock_queue_rcv_skb()
```

Then the userpsace get the data by:

```
recv();
... ...
-------system call --------- 
... ...
udp_recvmsg -->
__skb_recv_datagram -->
__skb_try_recv_datagram -->    (get the datagram from sk_receive_queue)
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, that explains most of my doubts, the rest I figured out by going through the code. I found it easier to add the custom header at the end of the datagram in the function `udp_send_skb` as it works seamlessly even when corking is enabled (I plan to use all the features of UDP)